# wget double-converting one file when mirroring a website and inserting absolute links

Tags: powershell, wget

[My issue is similar to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568972/links-issue-with-wget-on-windows), but I have more details than that one (and it doesn't have any answers).

I'm running the following command line from within a Powershell script to mirror a sharepoint site locally:

```
CMD.EXE /C ".\wget.exe --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent --no-cookies --ignore-case http://server.domain.com/foo/wiki/Home.aspx"
```

Virtually all of the pages are downloaded and converted correctly. One of them (that I've found) is not; the links in that single file are converted to absolute URLs (i.e. "http://server.domain.com/foo/site.css" rather than "../site.css"), even though files in the same directory are correctly converted (so it's not a path length issue).

I do note the following in the log:

```
Converting server.domain.com/foo/wiki/bar.aspx.html... 54-34
```

and then later in the log:

```
Converting server.domain.com/foo/wiki/bar.aspx.html... 21-33
```

So for some reason it's processing the file twice. The first time, the links get fixed correctly, and then the second time they get changed to the online links.

Before conversion the links in the erroring file look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css?rev=T%2Bhraxktc1A8EnaG5gGMHQ%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/wiki.css?rev=pOVpruQJauHtoX04fhoGSA%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=p63%2BuzTeSJc22nVGNZ5zwg%3D%3D"/>
```

After they look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://server.domain.com/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css@rev=T+hraxktc1A8EnaG5gGMHQ==.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://server.domain.com/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/wiki.css@rev=pOVpruQJauHtoX04fhoGSA==.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://server.domain.com/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css@rev=p63+uzTeSJc22nVGNZ5zwg==.css"/>
```

Before conversion the links in one of the correct files looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css?rev=T%2Bhraxktc1A8EnaG5gGMHQ%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/wiki.css?rev=pOVpruQJauHtoX04fhoGSA%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=p63%2BuzTeSJc22nVGNZ5zwg%3D%3D"/>
```

After they look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css@rev=T+hraxktc1A8EnaG5gGMHQ==.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/wiki.css@rev=pOVpruQJauHtoX04fhoGSA==.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css@rev=p63+uzTeSJc22nVGNZ5zwg==.css"/>
```

The site is not terribly large (about 92kb uncompressed).

Why the difference, and what can I do to make wget behave itself here?

Comment: Why even use the `--convert-links` flag? It seems to me that when you mirror a website you want to host it in a different location, thus allow it to work completely from the other server. The way you're doing it, all the links on your second server would point back to the first server. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am mirroring the site for offline (disconnected) viewing, meaning that I need to use the functionality of --convert-links so that "The links to files that have been downloaded by Wget will be changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.", to quote the [help page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're getting and what you're expecting. Can you edit you OP to make it more clear, please?